# Verb to Adjective "inviteable" or "invitable"?

Tags: adjectives, spelling

I really wonder what's the right way to make a verb to adjective?
"inviteable" or "invitable"?
"closeable" or "closable"?

Are there rules about these or it's just my decision which one to use?

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/able-eable?sort=votes&pageSize=45

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've never seen "invitable" spelled "inviteable"; in fact, "invitable" is a very uncommon word, but it exists.  I have seen "closable" spelled "closeable", so that's fine.  I think there are just alternate spellings of words as you've seen above.  In some instances, however, there are no alternate spellings. "Interchangeable" must always have the "e" before the morpheme ***-able***; it cannot be spelled "interchangable".  It would be wrong if it were spelled that way. Here are some alternate spellings of words:

> aether = ether
>
> aeon = eon
>
> apnoea = apnea
>
> colour = color
>
> practise (verb) = practice (verb)
>
> encyclopaedia = encyclopedia
>
> apophthegm = apothegm
>
> realise (verb) = realize (verb)

Some words have different spellings, but the pronunciations change when the spellings change:

> spelt (verb) = spelled
>
> leapt (verb) = leaped
>
> dreamt (verb) = dreamed
>
> leant (verb) = leaned
>
> crew (verb) = crowed
>
> shorn (verb) = sheared

This usually happens with verbs and not so much with other forms such as nouns and adjectives.  The reason for this is that certain verbs have variant past-tense and past-participle paradigms.

As for a general rule, I can think of none off the top of my head except that, often, but not always, a soft **g** sound allows the **e** to remain:

> swinge (verb) = swingeing
>
> singe (verb) = singeing

But this is not always the case:

> change = changing
>
> cringe = cringing

The spelling rules of English are all over the place.  You'll just have to learn how it's spelled and move on.  There are many words with variant spellings, so that can both aid you by giving you more choices and leeway, but it can also hinder you because it can be confusing as well.

I hope that might have helped you out.  Take care and good luck!

Comment: Hardly anyone writes [**citeable** instead of **citable**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=citable%2Cciteable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccitable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cciteable%3B%2Cc0), but a significant minority write [**writeable** rather than **writable**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=writable%2Cwriteable&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwritable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwriteable%3B%2Cc0). Usage is obviously changing though, so "correct" is a bit of a meaningless concept.

Answer (score 1):

A good rule of thumb is *if the removal of the final **e** changes the pronunciation, don't remove it*. It means we can't remove the e from words that end with a ⟨c⟩ or a ⟨g⟩:

- noti**cea**ble (/s/)
- mana**gea**ble (/d͡ʒ/)
- interchan**gea**ble (/d͡ʒ/) etc.,

you cannot remove the final *e* because if you do, you'll end up with:

- *noti**ca**ble (/k/)
- *mana**ga**ble (/g/)
- *interchan**ga**ble (/g/)

that is, the removal of the final e changes the pronunciation of the root words. So in the above words, the e keeps the original pronunciation.

I checked a few sources for this rule of thumb and almost all of them say that if the removal of the e doesn't change the pronunciation, the e is optional. So you can spell 'inviteable' as either 'invitable' or 'inviteable'. I would, however, spell it 'inviteable' because for me, the e indicates a long vowel (diphthong). Another exception to this is 'notable'; it's never spelt **noteable* because it's directly derived from [Old French](https://www.etymonline.com/word/notable).

Both *moveable* and *movable* are common. According to *Spell It Out by David Crystal*, *The Times* style guide recommends 'moveable' while *The Guardian* and *Observer* recommend 'movable'. ['Sizeable' and 'sizable'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sizable%2Csizeable&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csizable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csizeable%3B%2Cc0) are both common.

Some spellings with the *-**e**able* have become obsolete, for instance, [*confuseable*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=confuseable%2Cconfusable&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconfuseable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconfusable%3B%2Cc0) or are less common such as [useable](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=useable%2Cusable&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuseable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cusable%3B%2Cc0)

This can be verified at:

- [Dictionary of British English Spelling System - Greg Brooks](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=sgh2CAAAQBAJ&source=gbs_navlinks_s)
- [A Survey of English Spelling - Edward Carney](https://books.google.com/books/about/A_Survey_of_English_Spelling.html?id=LKu_sHE8WBYC&redir_esc=y)
- [Spell it out - David Crystal](https://books.google.com/books/about/Spell_It_Out.html?id=XBZKMSX8MggC&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y)

- <sub>I've marked ill-formed constructs with a preceding asterisk</sub>